# How to go back to last page when having child router?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

How to go back to last page when having child router?

Please see comments in code for details. Thanks

```
export class OneProductComponent {
  prevUrlPath:string = '';

  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  routerOnActivate(next:ComponentInstruction, prev:ComponentInstruction) {
    this.prevUrlPath = prev.urlPath;
  }

  goBack() {
    // I have to manually add "products/" here, but if I need 
    // go back to root home page. Then I shouldn't add "products/" here.
    // Is there a smart way to to this?
    this._router.navigateByUrl(`products/${this.prevUrlPath}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: `this._router.navigateByInstruction(new ResolvedInstruction(this.prevUrlPath, null, {}));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The angular 2 documentation on routing suggests that you use the window object instead https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html#!#find-our-way-back

```
goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in html tag

```html
 routerLink="../LASTPAGE"
```

try routerLink="../LASTPAGE"

Answer (score 0):

Latest docs for Angular 7.2.7 (inspired by @Victor's link) basically say to use the injected Location service to achieve the same thing.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#find-the-way-back

(Copied from the sample)

In the template:

```
<button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
```

And the component:

```
goBack(): void {
  this.location.back();
}
```